# Chrome extension that finds a button(as soon as it appears) and clicks on it (ON A THIRD PARTY WEBSITE)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm in dire need to know if this is achievable.
I'm trying to just click a button that says "Ready" after a match was found, on a third party website.

So far I've looked everywhere but nobody has ever asked this question before, I have created the "barebones" chrome extension but I can't figure out how to find what I need to do in order to achieve this.

Comment: Possible, sure. I'd prefer a userscript, they require less overhead

Answer (score 0):

it is possible first you need to get an chrome extension 
that allow custom script to be runned on other site

than you can use this code

```
   function callscript() {
 var buton = document.getElementsByTagName('button').innerHTML;
 if (btn == "Ready") {
    btn.click();
}
 else {
   console.log('sa');
 }
}
```

Comment: Like GreaseMonkey?

Comment: it's not for my site it's for a third party website

Comment: then you can find a open source chrome extension on github that triggers a click and modify it

Comment: I managed to do it with ClassName instead of TagName but it just keeps clicking the button ad infinitum... I want it to hit it only once, which it does, but then after a match was found and I'm presented with a "CONNECT" button it keeps clicking on it even though it's not the same button, it has firstVariable_name (aka my first button variable name) and then secondVariable_name (second button variable name) so its 'firstvar + secondvar' for the second button and the classname thinks its the button i need because it contains firstvariable_name ... any way to fix it?

Comment: you can use classname[0] to only hit first occurance of class or tag

Comment: a bit late but figured out classname[classname.length - 1] has fixed my issue :)